# Is there a generalization of Floquet theory to elliptic functions?

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions, differential-operators

Hi,

Consider  a system of linear differential equations
$$
{d f \over dz} = A(z) f,
$$
where $A(z)$ is a matrix-function. If $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and the function is periodic $A(z) = A(z + T)$, Floquet theorem applies.

I am curious to know if there exists a generalization of Floquet theorem to the case, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$
and $A(z)$ is a doubly-periodic elliptic  function of $z$.

Thanks,

Victor

Comment: The Lamé equation http://dlmf.nist.gov/29 seems to be the canonical example analogous to the Mathieu equation.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant to your purpose, but the Wiki page says that the Floquet theorem generalizes to the Bloch theorem in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

After some searching around, it looks to me that it was Picard who thought of generalizing Floquet theory to linear ODEs with doubly-periodic coefficients (though according to [this paper](http://www.ams.org/proc/1998-126-04/S0002-9939-98-04668-1/S0002-9939-98-04668-1.pdf), Floquet himself worked a bit on this generalization, deriving his theory for ODEs with singly periodic coefficients from the more general case).

Comment: Hi JM -- Thanks for the paper. Very useful. I definitely should improve my google-searching skills, as I could not find anything sensible. 

Anyway, I am sort of amazed that such a natural question is not discussed in detail in any but a very few papers. When this question first came up in my (physics) research, I was hoping to quickly find a book or review on it. All the best

Answer (score 2):

Another, far reaching, aspect of Floquet theory in differential equations
$$a_0(z)f^{(n)}(z)+\cdots+a_nf(z)=0$$
with holomorphic coefficients is Fuchs theory of **monodromy**, where the leading coefficient $a_0$ has a zeros at $z_0$. You cannot solve a Cauchy problem at $z_0$, but you can solve it in a pointed disk $D\setminus z_0$. When you follow a circle around $z_0$, the coefficients look periodic.